# Docker file for nodejs doesn't execute node ./bin/www

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I used a docker file to execute package.json file but it stops at

GithubDatasetAPI@0.0.0 start /usr/src/app node ./bin/www

and doesn't go further or doesn't display error message.I updated to "\node ./bin/www" but doesn't work for me

Here is my DOCKERFILE

```
FROM node:8

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm install --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8082
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: Hi kartith kumar, welcome to StackOverflow. It looks like you may have pasted in the Dockerfile directly and it got automatically formatted with markdown. Try surrounding your code in three backticks ``` on the top and bottom instead, this will format it as code. For more information, check out https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: You copy . . Already, why bother copying the package.json that way? Put the `npm install` after

Answer (score 0):

try to copy all the files not just package.json

```
COPY ./ ./
```

instead of

```
COPY package*.json ./
```

Comment: tried but still  face same issue . below is the terminal last three lines                                                                             npm info ok
npm info lifecycle GithubDatasetAPI@0.0.0~start: GithubDatasetAPI@0.0.0

> GithubDatasetAPI@0.0.0 start /usr/src/app
> node ./bin/www